# Magento 1.8 Adyen Integration

Tags: magento-1.8, php-7

I have an issue with the adyen-magento module. When the payment is successful in adyen, the order status doesn't updated in Magento, so the order is not getting processed. Even though when the payment is confirmed in adyen, the order status doesn't updated in Magento. Can someone help me to figure this out please?

Answer (score 1):

Often this issue comes up because notifications are not properly set up, or your cron job is not running.

Check your notification setup: https://docs.adyen.com/plugins/magento-1/set-up-adyen-customer-area-m1/#step-2-set-up-notifications

Configure your cron: https://docs.adyen.com/plugins/magento-1/set-up-the-plugin-in-magento-m1/#step-2-run-cron

P.S. I work at Adyen :)

Comment: ok back to work pls

Comment: Hi Thanks,I did check with adyen, it sends positive response but in magento it is not getting processed(failed response).
Also this is happening only with few orders.
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: If this is only happening to a subset of your orders, and you've checked both your notifications and cron setup, I would recommend reaching out to support@adyen.com so they can troubleshoot the specific orders affected. Please send over the affected PSP references. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For us it was the notification url. Also make sure this url is outside of any cache mechanism that you have in place.

If you log into Adyen you should see warnings about notification url giving bad response. Trouble is last time I used the notification test screen it was buggy and gave false positives.

Also if I remember right there is a config within the official extension to password protect notification url. Make sure that matches config in adyen.  If the notification url is specific to a store in multistore make sure the settings are set at store level.

Comment: Hi Thanks,
This is happening only with few of the orders, my guess is not with the notification URL, is there anything else that could go wrong?